# Python + Selenium: Is there a way to use selenium webdriver as a module

Tags: python, linux, selenium

Let's say i have a file `main.py` like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("some_url")

username = browser.find_element_by_id( "username" )
password = browser.find_element_by_id( "password" )
submit   = browser.find_element_by_id( "submit"   )

username.send_keys( "some_user_name" )
password.send_keys( "hunter2" )

submit.click()
```

which opens a selenium driven instance of chrome, opens some page and logs me in.

I would like to split this up like this:

`main.py`

```
from sub_dir import bcd

main():
  abc.get_page("some_url")
  bcd.login("some_user_name", "hunter2")
  bcd.1()
  bcd.2()
  bcd.n()
```

---

`bcd.py`

```
import abc

def login(uname, upass):
  username = abc.browser.find_element_by_id( "username" )
  password = abc.browser.find_element_by_id( "password" )
  submit   = abc.browser.find_element_by_id( "submit"   )

  username.send_keys(uname)
  password.send_keys(upass)

  submit.click()

def 1...n():
```

---

`abc.py`

```
from selenium import webdriver

def setup_selenium():
   browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def get_page(query):
   browser.get(query)
```

So the structure looks like this

```
main-dir\
    main.py
    sub-dir\
        abc.py
        bcd.py
```

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. What has Selenium to do with this? This more looks like python code organization strategy problem

Comment: Yeah, i see what you are meaning. Quite new to python so it is not impossible that i'm just to stupid to get this working. When i'm back home i will edit this to (hopefully) clarify what i meant